# Deep CNN with variable number of classes and "vanishing" data

Tags: multiclass-classification, cnn

I am using a deep CNN to predict the class an image belongs to (N classes). However, the number of classes is not stationary. I.e. over the time the network will be used, some new classes may emerge while others may not be relevant anymore (I do not need to identify these in any way but I know the relevant classes at any time step).

Additionally, I am facing the constraint that the data I can use for this task "vanishes". This means that, at a point in time, I can only use the data of the previous M time steps (e.g. months) where M remains constant. This prohibits simply retraining the network on the entire dataset here and then while dropping some classes/adding new classes (i.e. changing the size of the output layer).

I was thinking of using the feature extracting part of the CNN to generate the feature vector and then use binary classifiers (e.g. logistic regressions) on that. This would enable me to simply discard a binary classifier when a class has become irrelevant or add a new binary classifier in case a new class comes up. This approach would take significantly more time in the inference stage (training stage is not critical) as inference would need to be performed for each class separately. Unfortunately, I am also facing tight time constraints at the inference stage.

Therefore, I was wondering whether (A) my idea generally makes sense and (B) if there is a more elegant/efficient multi-class classification approach (i.e. a single inference step) that is applicable in my very special case.

Comment: How are the new classes being introduced to the system? Is there some kind of feedback loop (e.g. user given a wrong classification requests to make a new class out their example, online)? When a new class is introduced, how many examples of that class will you have to work with? Just one?

Comment: The new class is introduced by a feedback loop from the host of the service. Say a we are doing this for a zoo to recognize their animals on pictures. When the zoo gets a new animal, it tells us that it got a new animal and provides us with a few samples (1-10) initially. This sample size then grows over time through a feedback loop when we misclassify an unseen sample in production.

Comment: This looks like a very interesting question. So, what did you end up doing?